# Check Jupyter cells executed in sequence

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pre-commit.com

I would like to enforce a policy that all Jupyter notebooks that are checked into a git repository were run top to bottom. That is, I would like to check whether the cells in the notebook were executed in sequence.

Are there any existing solutions for this problem? Are there simpler ways to do this than parsing the raw notebook json?

Comment: seeking tools is off topic on SO as it tends to attract spammy link-only answers

Answer (score 1):

A few hours later, this has turned into a `pre-commit` hook Python package. May I present [notebooks-in-order](https://github.com/RoyalTS/notebooks-in-order)!

Comment: Probably better suited in the Show and Tell category at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/c/general/show-and-tell/45).